# Mobile App(iPhone / Android) app to read real time text from camera

Tags: android, ios, ocr

I want to programmatically read numbers on a page using mobile's camera instead from image, just like barcode scanning. 
I know that we can read or scan barcode but is there any way to read numbers using same strategy. Another thing is i also know that we can read text or numbers from image using OCR but i don't want to take the photo/image and than process it but only scan and get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean to say that you don't want to click a picture and process it, instead you want to scan text by just hovering the camera, am I right?

It could be accomplished using a technology called [Optical Character Recognition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). (You mentioned something about OSR, I think this is want you meant).  What it does is, it finds patterns in images to detect text in printed documents.

As far as I know, existing tools processes still images, so you will have to work around it to make it scan any moving images.

Character recognition demands significant amount of resources, so instead of processing moving pictures I would recommend you to write a program that takes images less frequently from a hovering camera and process it. Once text, or numbers in your case, are detected you could use a less efficient pattern matching algorithm to track the motion of the numbers.

Till date, the most powerful and popular software is [Tesseract-OCR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)). You will find it at [GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr). You can use this to develop your mobile application.

Comment: Yes! You get it right, My requirement is not to take still images and i was talking about OCR(OSR was a typing mistake).

Comment: There are OCR engines that instead of still images, they work on video streams, and on certain use cases produce better results than still image OCR.